# Dynamic size of telerik grid

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, telerik

I have the following grid in a ASP.NET MVC project.

```
<div class="actualGrid" id="actualGrid">
        @(Html.Kendo().Grid<PROJECT.Models.Bench>()
            .Name("grid")

        .Columns(columns =>
        {
            columns.Bound(p => p.name).Title("Bench").Filterable(ftb => ftb.Cell(cell => cell.Operator("contains"))).Width(125);
            columns.Bound(p => p.freeSeats).Title("Free Seats").Width(350);

            columns.Command(command => { command.Custom("checkBench1 ").Text(" AM ").Click("doCheckIn"); command.Custom("checkBench 2").Text(" PM ").Click("doCheckIn"); command.Custom("checkBench3").Text("All Day").Click("doCheckIn"); }).Width(250).Title("Check in");

        })


        //.Editable(editable => editable.Mode(GridEditMode.PopUp))
        .Pageable()
        .Sortable()

        .Scrollable()
                .Filterable(ftb => ftb.Mode(GridFilterMode.Row))
        .HtmlAttributes(new { style = "height:530px;" })
                .Events(events => events.DataBound("onDataBound"))
        .DataSource(dataSource => dataSource
        .Ajax()
        .PageSize(20)
        .Events(events => events.Error("error_handler"))
        .Model(model => model.Id(p => p.id))
                        .Read(read => read.Action("GetBenches", "Home"))


                )
        )
    </div>
```

I would like to know if there is a way to change the `size(height)` of the grid according to the number of results I have when I use filter.

For Example if I filter first column and get 1 result grid would be small, and if I had 10 results it would be larger.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

use this line for it:

```
.Scrollable(scrolling => scrolling.Enabled(false))
```